# Bash / Shell Script: How to time a specific portion of an application

Tags: linux, bash, shell, timing

I'm having some issues with getting my bash script to time a certain portion of an application. I have two scripts:

Bash Script 1 (timing.sh):

This is the main script and its purpose is to provide inputs into our test script and time a certain process it does before printing it.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1

# Use spawn to open the test process
spawn ./test.sh

# Use expect to wait for the previous spawned process (test.sh) to output an expected string
# Use send to write y or n to the spawned process stdin
expect "Press any key to continue"
send "\r"

expect "Do you want to proceed? (y/n)"
send "y\r"

# Start timer
set start_time [clock seconds]

# There is another prompt that needs input (this is to run the actual application)
expect "Start the process? (y/n)"
send "y\r"

# Stop the timer and output execution time
set end_time [clock seconds]
set elapsed_time [expr $end_time - $start_time]
puts "Application Time: $elapsed_time seconds"
```

Bash Script 2 (test.sh):

This script is meant to be used as a basis before running Script 1 with the actual application. It has a loop that is supposed to take about 5 seconds to run. The goal is to get Script 1 to only time the loop portion of the script. It's a bit confusing as to why there are user inputs when they aren't being used anywhere else on the test script, but it is meant to merely imitate the process of the actual application.

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script is meant to test the timing.sh script
# The process below is supposed to take about 5 seconds to run and we want the timing script to only time the loop process and not the stuff that requires user input

# Prompt user for any input
read -n1 -r -p "Press any key to continue" key

# Prompt the user to answer yes or no
read -p "Do you want to proceed? (y/n)" answer_1

# Prompt the user to answer yes or no
read -p "Start the process? (y/n)" answer_2

# Set duration of the loop in seconds
duration=5

# Set start time
start_time=$(date +%s)

# Run a loop until duration is reached
while [[ $(($(date +%s) - $start_time)) -lt $duration ]]
do
    # Action within loop
    for i in {1..10}
    do
        echo "Loop iteration $i"
        sleep 0.5 # sleep for half a second
    done
done
```

The test.sh script works just fine, correctly outputting the loop iterations. The issue is the timing.sh script that outputs time as a big fat 0:

```
[root@localhost Timing_Testing]# ./timing.sh 
spawn ./test.sh
Press any key to continue
Do you want to proceed? (y/n)y
Start process? (y/n)FW Update Time: 0 seconds
```

Ignore the bad formatting. Actually, looking at it now, the input for the second prompt doesn't go through. Why is that? And would correcting that fix the timing for the loop process?

Comment: The second `send "y\r"` will send and return immediately, at which point you grab the stop time.  You are not WAITING for the application to complete, so you are not actually timing the application.  For the timing to work, you will need to "expect" some string that gets printed when the job is done.  Alternatively, use the bash `time` command to start the command with timing.

Comment: I see. So I add `puts "Process Finished!"` in the end of the test.sh script. Then in my timing.sh script I change the second `send "y\r"` to `send "y\n"` (Not entirely sure if that would change anything I'm still new to this). But then where would I put the expect for "Process Finished!"? I'm assuming right before the stopping the timer?

Comment: Just tested it out. Yeah just put `expect "Process Finished!"` before stopping the timer and it works

Comment: FWIW, `timing.sh` is misnamed. It is not a "Bash Script" at all.